# Unfinished transitions in Edge

Tags: css, opacity, transition, microsoft-edge

There is a bootstrap modal which appears on button click.
There are also several tabs opened in Edge browser.
I am doing the following:

1. Click the button - the modal starts to appear
2. Switch to another tab - the modal is not fully visible yet and some transitions are in progress
3. Switch back to the original tab with modal which is semitransparent now
4. Transitions seem to be unfinished and modal becomes semitransparent

If I type the next code in console it gives me:

```
var m = angular.element('.modal.fade.in');
m.css('opacity') -> 0.2666
m.css('opacity') -> 0.2333
m.css('opacity') -> 0.33
//and so on..
```

I assume there is some optimization process that suspends not focused pages and resumes only focused pages and maybe for some reason transitions remain unfinished - styles are not fully applied.

How can I handle this situation?
Simply resizing window fixes the problem but that is not acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution I used the folowing code:

```
window.onfocus = function() { 
  //manually check css opacity
  //if is is less than 1 - set it 1
}
```